# Anyone using CDC and having performance issues extracting net_changes? We have 8 tables tracked with CDC "@support_net_changes=1"

Tags: sql-server-2019, change-data-capture

So 8 tables are being tracked with CDC "@support_net_changes=1".   7 of them are ok in regards to performance.  As some of these tables are only 10-40 million rows and data doesn't change that drastically.  Default purge of 3 days for CDC tables is used.   But one table "TESTS"  (GE Proficy PlantApps App) has 1.2 billion rows and is very active.  Its CDC capture table cdc.dbo_TESTS_CT has about 1.8 million rows in it (215MB is its size).   Command for CDC is: EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table @source_schema = N'dbo', @source_name=N'TESTS', @role_name = NULL, @supports_net_changes = 1;

Developer is extracting/detecting changes from it via:

```
SELECT  *
FROM CDC.FN_CDC_GET_NET_CHANGES_DBO_TESTS(ISNULL(sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than or equal',CAST('2024-03-21 09:02:10.477' AS DATETIME)), [sys].[fn_cdc_get_min_lsn]('DBO_TESTS') ), sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', GETDATE()), 'all');
```

This net_changes query will run for all day... until I kill it.   I pasted plan XML in BrentOzar pastetheplan and its pretty ugly in size.   But its dealing with a 1.8 million row CDC table.  Just makes no sense in regards to processing time.   This is a 8core AOAG SQL Server 2019 Enterprise CU23 VM with maybe 10-15% typical CPU load with DellEMC all-flash.  It is using many of the CDC indexes that "@support_net_changes=1" creates.

Update:  3/25:
I went to a simple CDC select/extract as the statement had many functions/params/logic in it.   It ran in 11 seconds and selected 446k rows.   We are checking into this.
DECLARE @begin_time DATETIME, @end_time DATETIME, @begin_lsn BINARY(10), @end_lsn BINARY(10);

SELECT @begin_time = GETDATE()-1, @end_time = GETDATE();
SELECT @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', @begin_time);
SELECT @end_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('largest less than or equal', @end_time);

SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_TESTS(@begin_lsn,@end_lsn,'all');
Also net_changes call is also faster - 3 seconds:
SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_TESTS(@begin_lsn,@end_lsn,'all');

Comment: CDC Developer is not well experienced with CDC extraction - so wondering if he's using correct SQL functionality.

Comment: "*I pasted plan XML in BrentOzar pastetheplan*" - Please link it in your post.

Comment: Note the query returns rows within a few seconds - but it runs many hours and never seems to finish - where query thread has to be killed.   Paste the plan link is:  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1XHQLoAp

Comment: Ran a new query - and CDC query for TESTS ran in 5min 40 secs and selected 937,285 rows.   Just for the big TESTS CDC table.  If they want to run the extract process for all 8 tables every 10 mins this won't work.  Right now they are extracting hourly any data in TESTS based on timestamp that has changed in 35 days and that "old school" process runs quicker in about 2-3 minutes.

Comment: CDC data is auto purged by default after 4 days.   I used an older date "Mar 21" which is why it was faster.   I am using a more current date Mar 24 and it is running for over an hour... killing it.   As we need to have it running in a minute.

Comment: I ran a less complicated select:  and it ran in 10 secs and returned 401,802 rows:  I am unable to paste the code example as the "@" variables are pissing off the comment edit logic - code example is from: https://malapatidatabase.wordpress.com/2017/08/22/how-to-analyze-and-read-change-data-capture-cdc-records/    We are still investigating.

Comment: You should add updates into your post instead of comments. Aside from formatting limitations, updates in the comments are easily missed by the community.